# Sounds for Charging the Samsung galaxy s 3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Can someone tell me how to turn( on) the sound for when my Samsung galaxy s 3 is charged.        Please, 
                       than you!

Comment: We don't find this option actually in almost all Android phones. It is a nice idea if there is an option like that. Let us wait for any nice answers...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) to do this. I haven't checked it by myself. But from the tutorial, it is possible to change profile(ring/vibrate/silent) at a particular battery level (using [%BATT](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/variables.html) variable) or a battery full event(if there is one).